# How to get all data from Opencart Store for Mobile App

Tags: react-native, opencart, opencart2.x

I am developing IOS/Android app with React Native and need all data from Opencart Store. How can I get and post to my opencart Store?

Comment: checkout the API docs of Opencart store. It should have the answer to your question.

Comment: You can refer to this : `http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/system/users/api/` or else use a 3rd party extension like this one `https://opencart-api.com/`. This should give you full access to all Data for Mobile App development

Answer (score -1):

After searching found this on Opencart documentation:
http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/system/users/api/

Comment: If you want to contribute something useful, it needs to be more than a link.  Tell us what you did, provide an example of how you solved your problem.  That way it might help other users who find this question.

Comment: It was not a problem I just did not know where to start. In the link mentioned above, Opencart Documentation, everything is explained very clearly.